# How can I replicate the "give app permission to access documents" on the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, security, privacy

Following up from this question: [What does it mean to give apps access to Documents folder on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415964/what-does-it-mean-to-give-apps-access-to-documents-folder-on-mac)

How can one replicate the "give apps access" process on the command line? I ask because I'm dealing with an application from a major publisher that is complaining that it still doesn't have access even after the settings have been changed in the Privacy and Security menu.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to set out an answer, but it's covered by `tccutil`. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=tccutil for starters. Hope someone comes a long with better info. Also note that this permission will always fail unless you have SIP enabled [fixable in most circumstances, but not if you're using OpenCore to enable a more up to date macOS.]